# Can java access ASP.Net Session Data in Memory if both apps are on the same server and Java has the Session ID?

Tags: java, asp.net, spring, session, windows-server

I am building a java Rest Service that is located on the same server as a .Net application. The client is hosted within the .Net Application but it communicates with a Java Rest Service. We need some way of accessing the Users Session data in .Net without altering the .Net code. So my question is...

If the java Rest Service app is located on the same server as the ASP.NET app. This means ASP.NET is saving the users information on the servers memory. If we have the Session ID. And its  past to java, is it possible for Java to retrieve that information in memory by using the Session ID ?

In general what are my possibilities.

The java application and the ASP.NET application are both on the same server and on a windows server.

Thanks

Comment: One portable method to consider is using sockets to communicate between the two processes.

Comment: Is there method that does not require me changing ASP.NET code ?